# Get reference to assembly from code generation tool

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, reflection, code-generation

I'm currently implementing a custom code generator that converts XML config files to C# classes within a Visual Studio project. I'm basically following the approach described in this blog post: http://consultingblogs.emc.com/pauloreichert/archive/2005/05/21/1459.aspx

However, the code generator has to look-up all available types and their properties inside the assembly in which the generator is used. I want to do this using reflection, but the problem is that I need a reference to the assembly in which to look for the types.

How can I get a reference to the assembly of the VS project the code generator is used in?

Comment: Sounds similar to this http://csd.codeplex.com/ its open source, perhaps its code will help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution. Indeed, it is possible to get a reference to Visual Studio Project object from within the code generator.

I found the code for getting the project reference here: http://subversion.assembla.com/svn/mistral-framework/trunk/src/VisualStudio/Mistral.VisualStudio.XmlClassGenerator/BaseCodeGeneratorWithSite.cs

The following method then returns a reference to the assembly object, which we can use to get all available types, etc. via reflection.

```
private static Assembly GetAssembly(Project project, string assemblyName)
{
    Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.IServiceProvider oleSP = 
        project.DTE as Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.IServiceProvider;
    ServiceProvider sp = new ServiceProvider(oleSP);

    DynamicTypeService dts = 
        sp.GetService(typeof(DynamicTypeService)) as DynamicTypeService;

    Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsSolution sln = 
        sp.GetService(typeof(SVsSolution)) as IVsSolution;

    Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsHierarchy hier = null;
    sln.GetProjectOfUniqueName(project.UniqueName, out hier);

    ITypeResolutionService rs = dts.GetTypeResolutionService(hier);
    return rs.GetAssembly(new AssemblyName(assemblyName), true);
}
```

The method still requires the assembly name, which is fine in my case since I can read it from the XML base file for generation. However, I am pretty sure you can get the reference without the name as well. (I was just lazy and stopped investigating when I got it to work;-)

Answer (score 0):

Note that in order to produce the assembly, Visual Studio needs to compile the C# code that is output by your tool. Thus, at the time your code generator is runnig, there might be no assembly yet (if this happens tone a clean build).

Comment: That makes total sense, but I think you're already one step ahead... I don't know how I actually have to reference the assembly.

Comment: My point is that(as far as I know :-)) you can't reference the assembly, because it does not make any sense for VS to give you the ability to reference something that might not exist. :-)

Comment: OK. But aren't there any other ways for looking up the available types in the project which is using the custom tool for code generation? Maybe I rather need a reference to the Visual Studio project object or something similar?

Comment: There are two problems - 1) how to get access to the Visual Studio Extensibility object For the project, and I am not aware of a way for code generators to do this; and 2) how to get information for all types in the project output assembly, before all code is generated, a specially in the case where some of those types might come from a custom code generators (like your tool for example), which I think is impossible, since there is no information about the types, until the build is run and all code is compiled.

Comment: Theoretically, if you get access to the list of items in the project, you might be able to enumerate all C# files and compile them on the fly to get the metadata for types in them. However, you can't do anything about types that will be generated from the EF modeling language, until the build has run the EF code generator; and there is no guarantee that the build will run the EF code generator before your code generator.

Comment: It's not what I want to hear;-) but I guess you might be right. However, I'd consider your first point being the actual problem. Once I have a reference to the VS project, it should be possible to get the path of its bin folder and load the assembly with System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(path). (I'd still have to compile the application before I can use the code generator, but that would be perfectly fine in my case since I only have to look up types which are represented by static, non-generated .cs files.)